# Visual Studio Setup Project folder permission

Tags: visual-studio

I have a setup project that installs my app to the typical program files directly.

My app periodically saves some temporary images to the apps installation folder. It seems on Vista, the permissions are not setup for write permissions. I can change it manually in windows explorer and it works, but I would rather have the setup project do that automatically.

How can I do this?

Is there a better/more normal place to put temp images that won't have permissions issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not Vista specific, this will happen with any kind of user account that doesn't have admin privileges.  Your program just can't write to folders like c:\program files\blah.  That UAC disables admin privileges has been publicized for a long time now.  Use Environment.GetFolderPath() to get the path to an ApplicationData folder that you can write to.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756940.aspx for details on UAC issues for vista.   These problems can also occur in other versions of windows when running applications from non-admin accounts.  You should only write data to app data or temp directories and not program files.